# Update Action Returns Error

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I created an entity that has an image/file field in it. The insert and the render of the records in this entity works perfectly, but the update function, to modify some or all the fields of the entity, return this error:

> Error: Call to a member function move() on a non-object

So I suppose that the error is in the function moveImage() in entity itself, that is:

```
    /**
 * @ORM\PostPersist()
 */
public function moveImage()
{
    if (null === $this->image)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (!is_dir($this->getUploadRootDir()))
    {
        mkdir($this->getUploadRootDir());
    }
    copy($this->getTmpUploadRootDir() . $this->image, $this->getFullImagePath());
    unlink($this->getTmpUploadRootDir() . $this->image);
}
```

I don't know what is the problem, and if I'm guessing right. Any suggest?

This is the entity:

```
    <?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Ricette
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\RicetteRepository")
 */
class Ricette
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="titolo", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $titolo;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ingredienti", type="text")
     */
    private $ingredienti;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="procedimento", type="text")
     */
    private $procedimento;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="quantita", type="integer")
     */
    private $quantita;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="difficolta", type="integer")
     */
    private $difficolta;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tempo", type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $tempo;

    /**
     * @var string $image
     * @Assert\File( maxSize = "60000000", mimeTypesMessage = "Perfavore inserisci un'immagine valida!")
     * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $image;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tipologia", inversedBy="ricette")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tipologia_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $tipologia;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set titolo
     *
     * @param string $titolo
     *
     * @return Ricette
     */
    public function setTitolo($titolo)
    {
        $this->titolo = $titolo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get titolo
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitolo()
    {
        return $this->titolo;
    }

    /**
     * Set ingredienti
     *
     * @param string $ingredienti
     *
     * @return Ricette
     */
    public function setIngredienti($ingredienti)
    {
        $this->ingredienti = $ingredienti;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get ingredienti
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getIngredienti()
    {
        return $this->ingredienti;
    }

    /**
     * Set procedimento
     *
     * @param string $procedimento
     *
     * @return Ricette
     */
    public function setProcedimento($procedimento)
    {
        $this->procedimento = $procedimento;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get procedimento
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getProcedimento()
    {
        return $this->procedimento;
    }

    /**
     * Set quantita
     *
     * @param integer $quantita
     *
     * @return Ricette
     */
    public function setQuantita($quantita)
    {
        $this->quantita = $quantita;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get quantita
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getQuantita()
    {
        return $this->quantita;
    }

    /**
     * Set difficolta
     *
     * @param integer $difficolta
     *
     * @return Ricette
     */
    public function setDifficolta($difficolta)
    {
        $this->difficolta = $difficolta;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get difficolta
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getDifficolta()
    {
        return $this->difficolta;
    }

    /**
     * Set tempo
     *
     * @param string $tempo
     *
     * @return Ricette
     */
    public function setTempo($tempo)
    {
        $this->tempo = $tempo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tempo
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTempo()
    {
        return $this->tempo;
    }

/**
     * Set image
     *
     * @param string $image
     */
    public function setImage($image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;
    }

    /**
     * Get image
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    public function getFullImagePath()
    {
        return null === $this->image ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir() . $this->image;
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        // the absolute directory path where uploaded documents should be saved
        return $this->getTmpUploadRootDir() . $this->getId() . "/";
    }

    protected function getTmpUploadRootDir() {
        // the absolute directory path where uploaded documents should be saved
        return __DIR__ . '/../../../web/immaginiRicette/';
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function uploadImage()
    {
        // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
        if (null === $this->image) {
            return;
        }
        if(!$this->id){
            $this->image->move($this->getTmpUploadRootDir(), $this->image->getClientOriginalName());
        }else{
            $this->image->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->image->getClientOriginalName());
        }
        $this->setImage($this->image->getClientOriginalName());
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     */
    public function moveImage()
    {
        if (null === $this->image)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (!is_dir($this->getUploadRootDir()))
        {
            mkdir($this->getUploadRootDir());
        }
        copy($this->getTmpUploadRootDir() . $this->image, $this->getFullImagePath());
        unlink($this->getTmpUploadRootDir() . $this->image);
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreRemove()
     */
    public function removeImage()
    {
        $file=$this->image;
        if($file = $this->getFullImagePath() && file_exists($file)) {
        unlink($file);
        rmdir($this->getUploadRootDir());
    }
    }

    /**
     * Set tipologia
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Tipologia $tipologia
     *
     * @return Ricette
     */
    public function setTipologia(\AppBundle\Entity\Tipologia $tipologia = null)
    {
        $this->tipologia = $tipologia;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tipologia
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Tipologia
     */
    public function getTipologia()
    {
        return $this->tipologia;
    }
}
```

Comment: You mapped your image property to string. It can't be both an uploaded file and a string. Go back to the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html

Comment: OK, I fixed it! Thank you! :) But now I have another problem: If I modify the image data, when I show the result (the record with the image field modified), it doesn't show the image, like it isn't able to find the new data I upload